# Operaciones con desde consola

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import det, inv, matrix_power

A = np.array([[-2.8, 7.3, 10.5],
              [8.5, 7.16, -9.4],
              [-2.35, 8.25, -1.6]])


B = np.array([[-1.25, 1.475],
              [-0.75, 5.015],
              [1, -2.85]])

C = np.array([[2.25, -0.5, 2.75],
              [-1, 0, -10.25]])

D = np.array([[-2, 2.35, -1],
              [2.25, 13.6, 2.36],
              [-9.3, -5.4, -5.25]])

ecuacion = int(input("Ingrese la ecuacion a opera:  "))
(print(ecuacion))
```

Buenas tengo este codigo. Necesito poder operar las matrices de manera que el usuario ponga la ecuacion. Tipo A+B, o A.dot(B) El problema es que al parecer los np.arrays son tipo none, por lo que no puedo hacer que lo que cuando el usuario ingrese A, lo tome como el array "A" definido antes.

gracias

Comment: la respuesta que te dieron es muy útil, recuerda que lo que devuelve un `input()` es un `string` y no podrás reemplazarlo por las variables definidas anteriormente, para eso usa `eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: Por mala interpretación de la pregunta había respondido de más ahora esta el contenido exacto de la pregunta:*

Para poder ejecutar una expresión como la presentas se puede usar la función `eval()`, esta función puede recibir como parámetro un `string` donde dentro debe haber una expresión como por ejemplo `3+3` o `x*y` y esta es ejecutada como si se tratara de una expresión *python*, esta función tiene la [mala fama](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-python-second/0596000855/ch15s06.html) de que si se llegase a ejecutar una expresión como `os.system('rm *')` podría eliminar todos los archivos en sistemas *linux*. En fin, mientras sepas lo anterior y lo uses con cautela (y si llegas a crear un programa para alguien mas tener mucho ojo si el usuario tiene acceso a este) se puede usar para lo que buscas:

```
ecuacion = input("Ingrese la ecuacion a opera:  ")
valor = eval(ecuacion)
print(valor)
```

Y al ejecutarlo:

```
Ingrese la ecuacion a opera:  A+D
[[ -4.8    9.65   9.5 ]
 [ 10.75  20.76  -7.04]
 [-11.65   2.85  -6.85]]
```

Información útil sobre los usos de [`eval()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)

*Nota: No podrás hacer un `A+B` como dices en la publicación pues para sumar matrices se debe cumplir que ambas matrices tengan las mismas dimensiones, si llegas a usar `eval(A+B)` te tirara un error.*

Comment: Ohh muchas gracias. Muy completa la info. Excelente servicio (?

Comment: Si te sirvió esta o otra respuesta, por favor puntuala y acepta una respuesta como la correcta, de esta forma algunos nos motivamos a seguir ayudando ^^~

Comment: Lastimosamente tengo menos de 15 puntos por lo que no puedo puntuarla

Comment: Como creador de la pregunta tienes la opción de seleccionar una respuesta como correcta (si no mal recuerdo bajo el símbolo de upvote)

Comment: Listo muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez lo que podrías usar es esto:

```
ecuacion = input("Ingrese la ecuacion a operar:  ")
print(eval(ecuacion))
```

La función `eval()` permite evaluar un string dado como si fuera código de python. En consecuencia, sirve para evaluar todo tipo de expresiones matemáticas. Sin embargo, también su uso es peligroso, ya que si el string contiene código mal intencionado, podría ejecutar codigo arbitrario. En consecuencia, sólo se debe usar cuando hay certeza de que el string que se va a evaluar viene de una fuente confiable, aunque también es posible limitar las cosas que son visibles desde dentro de `eval()`.

Saludos.

Comment: seria muy bueno explicar lo que hace la función `eval()` :)

Comment: Y los problemas que conlleva usarla fuera de prácticas...

Comment: Muchas gracias, y gracias por la explicacion. No sabia que existia esa funcion.